# Excel 2013 - Looking for a macro to write a sum for variable length sections

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a macro that will write a sum formula for a variable number of rows.

I have a bunch of sections on a fairly extensive sheet.  Each section has a column of costs, and each needs a sum at the end.  However, the sections are variable in length, so I can't just write one sum and copy/paste it to each section.

Sections are stacked like this:

Section Headers

- 1  Data  $
- 2  Data $
- 3  Data $

  Sum?

Section Headers

- 1  Data $
- 2  Data $
- 3  Data $
- 4  Data $
- 5  Data $
- 6  Data $
- 7  Data $

  Sum?

I have a few hundred of these to do, and I'd rather not manually write the sum formula each time.  The lower boundary of the range I need summed is always the same relative to the formula cell, but the upper boundary is a random number of rows higher.  Is there a way to have a macro auto detect how big the section is and make the sum only for that range?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there something consistent about the section headers that you could look for in VBA (e.g. each starts with a certain set of characters)? Or is there a blank row between each section? It would be relatively easy using a loop if you had some way to automatically determine the break between sections.

Comment: Each section has a column header marked "Corrections $" in the row above where the prices will start and a blank row above that separating the sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code assumes that each section heading starts with the word "Corrections" and that there are no blank rows between sections (so any blank cells will be filled with a sum formula). It also assumes the data is in column A. If your spreadsheet isn't setup like that, you could tweak this to work for your situation. Note that there isn't much in terms of error checking here, so you'll have to make sure your spreadsheet doesn't have any issues, or add error checks to the code (for example, if your spreadsheet doesn't start with a section heading, you may have an issue, and if you have sections with no values--that is a section header and then no data under it--you'll have an issue).

```
Dim wksh as worksheet
Dim last_row as long
Dim curr_start as long

set wksh = thisworkbook.worksheets("<your worksheet name>")
last_row = wksh.cells(wksh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

for i = 1 to last_row + 1
    if wksh.range("A"&i).value=0 or wksh.range("A"&i)="" then
        wksh.range("A"&i).formula = "=SUM(A" & curr_start & ":A" & i-1 & ")"
    elseif left(wksh.range("A"&i).value, 4)="Corr" then
        curr_start = i + 1
    endif
next i
```

Comment: I just saw your comment above and made some slight edits to the post--the one thing that would have to be added is allowing for the blank row in between sections. I think this could be done by changing the If statement to:  if (wksh.range("A"&i).value=0 or wksh.range("A"&i)="") AND (wksh.range("A"&i+1).value=0 or wksh.range("A"&i+1)="") then